# java spring-boot r2dbc liquibase

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

**Hello every, I write a reactiv rest API using Webflux and I want to use liquibase in this project. Whatever I do, the project works but liquibase does not create the tables in postgre.**

**Please Help me**

**Application.yml**

```
spring:
 profiles:
   active: local
 liquibase:
   enabled: true
   url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/liquebase
   user: postgres
   password: 12345
   change-log: classpath:/db/liquibase/db.changelog-master.yml
 datasource:
   driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
 r2dbc:
   url: r2dbc:pool:postgresql://localhost:5432/liquebase
   username: postgres
   password: 12345

server:
  port: 8085
```

**Main changelog yaml**

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - include:
     file: db/liquibase/create-label_entity-table.yml
  - include:
     file: db/liquibase/create-task_entity-table.yml
  - include:
     file: db/liquibase/create-project_entity-table.yml
  - include:
     file: db/liquibase/create-due_entity-table.yml
```

**create-due_entity-table.yml**

```
   databaseChangeLog:

-  changeSet:
     id: 2
   author: zaur
   changes:
     -  createTable:
          tableName: due_entity
          columns:
            -  column:
                 name: id
                 type: serial
                 autoIncrement: true
                 constraints:
                   primaryKey: true
                   nullable: false
            -  column:
                 name: dateData
                 type: Date
            -  column:
                 name: recurring
                 type: boolean
                 constraints:
                   nullable: false
            -  column:
                 name: stringData
                 type: varchar(150)
            -  column:
                 name: task_id
                 type: int
-  changeSet:
    id: addForeignKeyConstraint-01
    author: zaur
   changes:
    - addForeignKeyConstraint:
             baseTableName: due_entity
             baseColumnNames: task_id
             constraintName: fk_due_task
             referencedColumnNames: id
             referencedTableName: task_entity
             validate: true
```

**create-task_entity-table.yml**

```
  databaseChangeLog:

 -  changeSet:
     id: 1
   author: zaur
   changes:
     -  createTable:
          tableName: task_entity
          columns:
            -  column:
                 name: id
                 type: serial
                 autoIncrement: true
                 constraints:
                   primaryKey: true
                   nullable: false
            -  column:
                 name: comment_count
                 type: int
            -  column:
                 name: completed
                 type: boolean
                 constraints:
                   nullable: false
            -  column:
                 name: content
                 type: varchar(50)
            -  column:
                 name: url
                 type: varchar(255)
            -  column:
                 name: orderdata
                 type: int
            -  column:
                 name: priority
                 type: int
            -  column:
                 name: due_id
                 type: DueEntity
-  changeSet:
    id: addForeignKeyConstraint-02
    author: zaur
    changes:
    - addForeignKeyConstraint:
        baseTableName: task_entity
        baseColumnNames: due_id
        constraintName: fk_task_id
        referencedColumnNames: id
        referencedTableName: due_entity
        validate: true
```

**pom.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
 instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.WebFluxTestCodes</groupId>
<artifactId>WebFluxTestCodes</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>WebFluxTestCodes</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.remondis/remap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.remondis</groupId>
        <artifactId>remap</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.5</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-pool</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0.M1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <propertyFile>src/main/resources/application.yml</propertyFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

**Main Class**

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableR2dbcRepositories
 @ComponentScan("com.WebFluxTestCodes.WebFluxTestCodes.business.*")
 @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class})
 public class WebFluxTestCodesApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SpringApplication.run(WebFluxTestCodesApplication.class, args);
  }
```

}

**My Log**

```
       2021-03-14 09:16:19.472  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] c.W.W.WebFluxTestCodesApplication        
      : Starting WebFluxTestCodesApplication using Java 15.0.1 on WIN-3QMQSJHKUBK with PID 11796 
      (C:\Users\user\Desktop\TestWebService\WebFluxTestCodes\target\classes started by user in 
      C:\Users\user\Desktop\TestWebService\WebFluxTestCodes)
      2021-03-14 09:16:19.482  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] c.W.W.WebFluxTestCodesApplication        
      : The following profiles are active: local
      2021-03-14 09:16:19.898  WARN 11796 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.c.config.ConfigDataEnvironment     
      : Property 'spring.profiles' imported from location 'class path resource [application.yml]' is 
      invalid and should be replaced with 'spring.config.activate.on-profile' [origin: class path 
      resource [application.yml] - 19:13]
      2021-03-14 09:16:19.903  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    
      : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\user\.m2\repository\org\liquibase\liquibase- 
      core\3.10.3\liquibase-core-3.10.3.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: 
      file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.10.3/commons-cli- 
       1.4.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.10.3/snakeyaml- 
      1.24.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.10.3/slf4j-api- 
      1.7.28.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/3.10.3/logback- 
      classic-1.2.3.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/org/liquibase/liquibase- 
      core/3.10.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar
      2021-03-14 09:16:19.904  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
      .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 
      'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
       2021-03-14 09:16:19.905  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
       .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting 
       the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
       2021-03-14 09:16:23.031  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
       .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict 
          repository configuration mode!
         2021-03-14 09:16:23.034  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
         .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data R2DBC repositories in 
       DEFAULT mode.
     2021-03-14 09:16:23.519  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
        .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data R2DBC - Could not safely identify 
        store assignment for repository candidate interface 
        com.WebFluxTestCodes.WebFluxTestCodes.repository.LabelRepository. If you want this repository 
            to be a R2DBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these 
       annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table (preferred), or consider 
         extending one of the following types with your repository: 
        org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository.
       2021-03-14 09:16:23.528  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
      .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data R2DBC - Could not safely identify store 
          assignment for repository candidate interface 
         com.WebFluxTestCodes.WebFluxTestCodes.repository.ProjectRepository. If you want this 
        repository to be a R2DBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these 
         annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table (preferred), or consider 
       extending one of the following types with your repository: 
         org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository.
          2021-03-14 09:16:23.545  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
         .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data R2DBC - Could not safely identify 
         store assignment for repository candidate interface 
          com.WebFluxTestCodes.WebFluxTestCodes.repository.TasksRepository. If you want this 
        repository to be a R2DBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these 
           annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table (preferred), or 
        consider extending one of the following types with your repository: 
          org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository.
           2021-03-14 09:16:23.550  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
         .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 502 
          ms. Found 0 R2DBC repository interfaces.
            2021-03-14 09:16:24.072  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
          .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering 
           strict repository configuration mode!
           2021-03-14 09:16:24.073  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
           .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data R2DBC repositories in 
           DEFAULT mode.
            2021-03-14 09:16:24.097  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
         .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data R2DBC - Could not safely identify 
         store assignment for repository candidate interface 
        com.WebFluxTestCodes.WebFluxTestCodes.repository.LabelRepository. If you want this repository 
          to be a R2DBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: 
            org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table (preferred), or consider extending 
          one of the following types with your repository: 
          org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository.
          2021-03-14 09:16:24.100  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
         .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data R2DBC - Could not safely identify 
         store assignment for repository candidate interface 
         com.WebFluxTestCodes.WebFluxTestCodes.repository.ProjectRepository. If you want this 
          repository to be a R2DBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these 
          annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table (preferred), or 
         consider extending one of the following types with your repository: 
         org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository.
          2021-03-14 09:16:24.107  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
          .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data R2DBC - Could not safely identify 
         store assignment for repository candidate interface 
          com.WebFluxTestCodes.WebFluxTestCodes.repository.TasksRepository. If you want this 
         repository to be a R2DBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these 
        annotations: 
    org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table (preferred), or consider extending one of 
       the 
       following types with your repository: 
      org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.R2dbcRepository.
       2021-03-14 09:16:24.109  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
      .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : 
        Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 35 ms. Found 0 R2DBC repository interfaces.
          2021-03-14 09:16:29.681  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
           o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : 
           LiveReload server is running on port 35729
           2021-03-14 09:16:30.795  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
           o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : 
             Netty started on port 8085
              2021-03-14 09:16:30.840  INFO 11796 --- [  restartedMain] 
               c.W.W.WebFluxTestCodesApplication        : 
                Started WebFluxTestCodesApplication in 16.539 seconds (JVM running for 21.999)
```

Comment: Is there some more configuration that you haven’t shown? You’ve excluded the auto-configuration for Liquibase but don’t seem to have configured it yourself. How do you expect Liquibase to be invoked?

Comment: Andy I deleted autoconfiguratin now a databasechangelog has been created in the database but there is still an error

Comment: ERROR---> Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Error parsing classpath:db/liquibase/db.changelog-master.yml

Comment: Ok, so now there’s a problem with your change log for Liquibase. Hopefully the rest of the error message explains where the problem is so that you can correct it.